# Gnome/Unity apps -> fluxbox

Tags: fluxbox

Where could I find a list of all the commands used to execute the apps in Gnome/Unity so I can add them to my fluxbox menus?  i.e. user accounts/package manager/etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search in `/usr/share/applications/` for the corresponding `.desktop` files. They contain the command in the line starting with `Exec=`.

See the [Freedesktop Desktop Entry Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/index.html) for more about `.desktop` files.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu/Debian use update-menus to generate /etc/X11/fluxbox/fluxbox-menu.  This gets run from apt whenever you install or remove a package.  Slick!

So you can look there to see how apps are run (and yank the exact fluxbox menu command you'd need), or you can have in your ~/.fluxbox/menu:

```
    [submenu] (All Applications)
            [include] (/etc/X11/fluxbox/fluxbox-menu)
    [end]
```

Which is what I do.  That way I have my minimalist, carefully-curated list of applications and fluxbox options at the top of the menu, and the huge list of all applications installed on my system as an sub-menu.

Comment: For some reason when I run `update-menus` commans does not seem to update the menus with the installed apps via `apt-get` or `snap`.